# What is the difference between この一方で　and その一方で?

Tags: grammar

I don't understand why in this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/html/20180605/k10011465921000.html?utm_int=news-life_contents_list-items_001)  it is この一方で　and not その一方で that is used ?

> 櫻井さんによりますと、「断る」という行為は、コミュニケーションの中でも最も難しい部類に入るそうです。日本では古くから「察し型」の文化が根付いていて、多くを語らなくとも相手が分かってくれるはずだと考える人が多いと。**この一方で**、断られた人は自分の好意がむげにされたと感じ、相手のことを悪く思ったり、「もう次からはやめよう」と考えたりするというのです。

It's not the same structure that in these sentences ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you may already know,「一方」 by itself can be used to indicate that the following sentence(s) will be in a direction different from the preceding sentence(s). Please note that unlike 「反面」, which can only mean "Conversely" "On the other hand",「一方」 doesn't necessarily have to be moving in the opposite direction, which is why it can also mean "While" "Meanwhile" depending on the context.

Attaching 「その」 or 「この」 in front of 「一方」to refer to the context described by the preceding sentence(s) is just a matter of a sense of distance/perspective, although it should be noted that 「その」 is far more common. It's similar to how 「その中」and「この中」 are interchangeable when saying "while XX was happening" (Except 「一方」 can be used by itself but 「中」 can't in this context).

With these interchangeable wordings, it really comes down to writing style and the subtle nuances that the author wants to convey. The style in which that example is written is obviously not a standard formal writing style (i.e. 「なくとも」「多いと」「と言うのです」), and it appears to me that the writer is attempting to close the distance between them and the reader. I would argue that the use of 「この一方」is also part of that attempt to make the reader feel closer.

Comment: Downvoter, any suggestions for improving answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference in meaning.

「**そ**の一方{いっぽう}で」, as any dictionary would tell us, is a set phrase meaning "**on the other hand**", "***in the meanwhile***", etc.

「**こ**の一方で」 is **not** a set phrase.

In the context provided, 「**この**一方で」 would mean "***conversely***".  The first half is told from the perspective of the 「断{ことわ}る人」 (ones who deny others) and the second half (which is after 「**この**一方で」) is told from that of the 「断られる人」 (ones who are denied).  Following me so far?

The contents of the two halves mentioned above, therefore, are not exactly compared or contrasted.  Thus, the translation "on the other hand" would not fit in.  The best TL I could think of would be "conversely".

Comment: I don't understand why do you use the word "conversely" if they are not exactly compared or contrasted ?Since "conversely" is used to introduce a statement that contrasts with a previous statement.

 And also, I don't understand why the translation "on the other hand" would not fit in since it can be used to give the perspective of another type of person with rather opposite ideas as is the case in the NHK article ?